# Next.js 14 - Addressing Delay Issues in not-found.ts/tsx for Timely Rendering

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a custom `not-found.tsx` file located within my app's root router. In this file, I have a check where I attempt to fetch a page or a post.

If it doesn't exist, I return the built-in function from Next.js, `notFound()`.

However, the main issue is that initially, it displays the navigation and footer, both of which are contained within the footer with an empty . After a one-second delay, the not-found message or page becomes visible.

When I create my own custom component and run it on a 404, it works normally.

Code page.tsx:

```
import { Metadata } from "next"
import { draftMode } from "next/headers"
import { notFound } from "next/navigation"

import { toPlainText } from "@portabletext/react"
import { LiveQuery } from "next-sanity/preview/live-query"

import { getHomePageTitle, getPageBySlug, getPagesPaths, getSettings } from "@/lib/sanity.fetch"
import { pagesBySlugQuery } from "@/lib/sanity.queries"
import { defineMetadata } from "@/lib/utils.metadata"

import { Page, PagePreview } from "@/components/pages/page"

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: Params): Promise<Metadata> {
  const { slug } = params

  const [settings, page, homePageTitle] = await Promise.all([
    getSettings(),
    getPageBySlug(slug),
    getHomePageTitle()
  ])

  return defineMetadata({
    baseTitle: homePageTitle ?? undefined,
    description: page?.overview ? toPlainText(page.overview) : "",
    image: page?.ogImage || settings?.ogImage,
    title: page?.title
  })
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const slugs = await getPagesPaths()
  return slugs.map((slug) => ({ slug }))
}

export default async function PageSlugRoute({ params }: Params) {
  const data = await getPageBySlug(params.slug)

  if (!data && !draftMode().isEnabled) {
    // notFound()
    return (
      <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <h2>Not Found</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <LiveQuery
      enabled={draftMode().isEnabled}
      query={pagesBySlugQuery}
      params={params}
      initialData={data}
      as={PagePreview}
    >
      <Page data={data} />
    </LiveQuery>
  )
}
```

The not-found.tsx:

```
export default async function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
      <h2>Not Found</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```